# Print a vector with variable number of elements using sprintf

Tags: matlab, printf

In the following code, I can print all the elements in the vector `item` separated by a space as

```
item = [123 456 789];
sprintf('%d %d %d', item)

ans =

123 456 789
```

How do I go about doing this without having to enter as many `%d` as the number of elements in `item`?

Comment: I've edited and reworded the question so as to make the intent clear. Please feel free to make changes if you don't agree with it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The simplest answer is to note that [SPRINTF](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sprintf.html) will *automatically* cycle through all the elements of a vector you give it, so you only have to use *one* `%d`, but follow it or lead it with a space. Then you can remove extra white space on the ends using the function [STRTRIM](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/strtrim.html). For example:

```
>> item = [123 456 789];
>> strtrim(sprintf('%d ',item))

ans =

123 456 789
```

Comment: I was going to suggest that, but wasn't sure how to get rid of the last space. `strtrim` is a good function to know! +1

Answer (score 5):

I believe [`num2str`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/num2str.html) is what you're looking for.

```
item=[123 456 789]; 
num2str(item)

ans =

123  456  789
```

Since you also tagged it `sprintf`, here's a solution that uses it.

```
item=[123 456 789]; 
str='%d ';
nItem=numel(item);
strAll=repmat(str,1,nItem);

sprintf(strAll(1:end-1),item)

ans =

123 456 789
```

Comment: Yoda, this might not work.  The output has to sent to SQL Stored procedure which requires input from sprintf().  Please comment. Thanks!

Comment: @Maddy: I have a solution using `sprintf` too. See second half of my answer. I do not know SQL, so I can't comment on whether it will work or not. You could just try it on some test data and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Created a function as per the **above** answer and save it in a file named as the function name.

saved in file named as **print_vector.m** placed in folder **/home/${project_file_path}/functions**

```
function vector_as_string = print_vector(v)
str='%d ';
nItem=numel(v);
strAll=repmat(str,1,nItem);
vector_as_string = sprintf(strAll(1:end-1),v)
```

import in your program and use

```
addpath('/home/${project_file_path}/functions')
vector = [10 ; 20; 30;];
disp(sprintf('printing a vector using function %s \n', print_vector(vector));
```

outputs as:

```
printing a vector using function 10 20 30
```